# IE8 doctype changing

Tags: internet-explorer-8, doctype, vbulletin

I am currently using an XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype on my vBulletin website.  The page in question is PHP.  The source (view source) of this page verifies that the XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype is on the page.  Upon downloading (File > Save As) the page in IE8, I realized that my doctype had been replaced with an HTML 4.0 transitional doctype.

Why does IE8 change the doctype?

Why isn't the doctype its chosen displayed in the "View Source"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the global vBulletin options menu.

vBulletin Options -> Cookie and HTTP Header Options -> Send Internet Explorer 7 Compatibility Header (Yes/No)

Disabling that will prevent IE8 from rendering as IE7, and from using the 4.0 HTML transitional doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Please check which `Document` Mode Your `IE8` is running in. If it is IE8 then its some other error. If it's something else than IE8 please add this meta tag as the first element of the `<head>` Tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```